# What are some good ways to verify legitimacy of a commenter on a blog post?

Tags: design-patterns

I want to make sure that not just anyone is posting comments on a site - that is, I want to verify that its a legitimate person commenting. For example, having people write testimonials for a company profile. My initial idea was to be able to post comments with your Twitter handle or LInkedIn profile.

What are some other ways to achieve this without having to moderate?

EDIT: More specifically, what I'm trying to achieve is to figure out the best way for people to write testimonials for someone that they have worked with in the past (i.e. I am a client and I want to write my experience working with X). I don't want users who didn't work with that particular person to write malicious stuff.

From a ux perspective, would the following be obtrusive: Not only must the user must be logged into my website, but they must have a Twitter/LinkedIn or Facebook account connected to their profile in order to write a testimonial. This testimonial would then be sent to the person for their approval.

Comment: Hi @BeginnerUXStudent As it stands this question is not a UX related topic I'm afraid. Perhaps it could be reworded to make it one? Eg: How to validate comments without making the experience worse for legitimate users. Or something along those lines...

Comment: How would using twitter credentials resolve that issue?

Comment: @RogerAttrill - I don't understand why this isn't a UX related topic.  I can't see how this question is *that* different to the problem posed by the drink driver question (http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/14880/how-could-one-prevent-drunk-users-from-using-a-mobile-application). Each requires the application to assess some arbitrary quality about the user (legitimacy of identity / whether the user is drunk).

Comment: @codeinthehole - as asked it's a question about outline implementation and methods - and saving the site owner moderation time vs improving user experience as such. Sure, as a UX crowd we can put a UX spin on it, but the question would be better leaning towards this in the first place don't you think?

Comment: @RogerAttrill, I can understand what you're saying, but I'm tempted to say this question is fine. It's a common problem that directly affects the way people use a site.

Comment: I'd say that if you are the person who has to do the moderating its a very valid question.  I'd certainly be interested in some automated solutions.

Comment: I find it difficult to understand precisely what you are trying to achieve. Protect yourself against spam? Against reviews from people who are not actual customers but simply want to promote/shoot down the company in question? Against people posting several reviews under multiple identities? Against people being excessively aggressive (presumably because they are anonymous)? What's a legitimate user in your eyes?

Comment: The 'generic' question here is 'on a site based on user generated content such as user reviews - how do I maintain the quality of this content ?'. It's a difficult one.

Answer (score 1):

From a UX perspective, make it an unobtrusive as possible. Disqus does a reasonably good job with this, allowing you to post your comment and then log in with an ID system of your choice.

Tying comments to a stable ID with a reputation is an effective way to limit trolling and reign in unacceptable behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Provide users with the option to post comments directly without having to logging and once they have posted the comment ,give them the option to log in via a verified login name (which was created prior due to them registering on the site) or by linking with twitter or Facebook.

However do provide the feature to allow users to post anonymously but inform them that all anonymous comments are subject to moderation and it might take some time before their comments are available on the board.This will atleast moderate some users from posting malicious stuff and defeat malicious stuff from getting on the board while it also allows users to have a self of security from potential repercussions.

I personally think [glassdoor](http://www.glassdoor.com) does this well.They do require you to sign in to post reviews or interview information but they allow users to post anonymously and all comments and posts are checked to ensure conformity with community guidelines

Answer (score 0):

Let authenticated user's comments/feedback be published directly to your blog.
For the non-loggedin user, once they are done writing their comment give them two options (1)Submit your comment for moderation (2)Login to directly publish your comment.
This *might* defeat the anonymous+malicious user from posting.

Answer (score 0):

Re the EDIT:

How about requiring the person writing the testimonial about 'X' to enter their email which is automatically emailed to 'X' - and then get X to click on a link to confirm they know the person writing the testimonial ?

( like the authorisation of an email address process used when signing up to a website) ?